# Proper Syntax in a CodeIgniter Model

Tags: codeigniter, syntax

I'm trying to reuse variables in my Code Igniter Model but I can't quite get the syntax down. The problem I'm having is on line 4.

```
class Products_model extends CI_Model {

var $gcsServerIpAddress = "11.22.33.44";
var $gcsServerAddress = "http://".$this->gcsServerIpAddress."/eft/";
```

I've tried object syntax: $this->foo. I've also tried using the variable name: $foo. Neither of them worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the values inside the constructor.

```
class Products_model extends CI_Model {
    var $gcsServerIpAddress;
    var $gcsServerAddress;

    function __construct(){
        $this->gcsServerIpAddress = "11.22.33.44";
        $this->gcsServerAddress = "http://".$this->gcsServerIpAddress."/eft/"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've spend too much time typing loose php rather than doing things object oriented. I appreciate the reminder. :)